# PHP session preserved after header in one case, lost after header in another

Tags: php, session-variables

There are lots of posts about PHP sessions being lost after a header redirect. My issue is that I have one script where the session is preserved after a header redirect and another case where it isn't.

The session is preserved after the header redirect in this script:

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'settings.php';
include 'mysql_connect.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_email']);
$fbid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user_fbid']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['user_fb_id'] = $row['fb_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_pundit_name'] = $row['pundit_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
        header('Location: ' . $site_url . 'whats_next.php');
    }
} else {
    $insert_new_user = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, fb_id) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $fbid . "')"; 
    $result = $conn->query($insert_new_user);
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['user_fb_id'] = $fb_id;
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
    $msg = wordwrap("Congratulations " . $name . ",\nYou are now a registered Pundit. Like all pundits, you will be consulted for your wisdom from time from time to time. You will receive emails announcing an “open question” to be answered by you and your fellow pundits [or, if you have selected that option, you can go to PUNDITNETWORK.com and answer open question whenever you want.] The questions will usually ask you to forecast the outcome of an event in the near future. The question will remain open for a certain period of time. After that time, you can go to the Pundit forum at PUNDITNETWORK and discuss the question with fellow Pundits. We will add points to your Pundit rating for every right answer. High ratings can lead to recognition and prizes. As the PUNDITNETWORK grows, the opportunities for both recognition and prizes will also grow. In the meantime, enjoy the game! And feel free to challenge friends, relatives, classmates, teachers, co-workers or anybody who thinks he/she “knows it all” to test their skills and join you for a little friendly competition.", 70);
    mail($email, "Welcome to PunditNetwork", $msg);
    header('Location: ' . $site_url . 'whats_next.php');
}

?>
```

The session is not preserved after the header redirect in this script:

```
<?php

session_start();
include 'settings.php';
include 'mysql_connect.php';

$email = $_GET['email'];
$secret_key = $_GET['secret_key'];
$q = "SELECT * FROM email_confirmations WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND secret_key = '" . $secret_key . "'";
$r = $conn->query($q);
if ($r->num_rows > 0) {
    if($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
        $q1 = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = '" . $row['email'] . "'";
        $r1 = $conn->query($q1);
        if ($r1->num_rows > 0) {
            $q2 = "UPDATE users SET password = '" . $row['password'] . "' WHERE email = '" . $row['email'] . "'";
            $r2 = $conn->query($q2);
            $q3 = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = '" . $row['email'] . "'";
            $r3 = $conn->query($q3);
            if ($row3 = $r3->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row3['name'];
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row3['email'];
                $_SESSION['user_fb_id'] = $row3['fb_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_pundit_name'] = $row3['pundit_name'];
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row3['id'];
                // var_dump($_SESSION); // session is correct when var dumped
                header('Location: ' . $site_url . 'whats_next.php');
            }
        }
        /*
        else {
            $q2 = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('" . $row['name'] . "', '" . $row['email'] . "', '" . $row['password'] . "')";
            $r2 = $conn->query($q2); 
            $q3 = "SELECT * from users WHERE email = '" . $row['email'] . "'";
            $r3 = $conn->query($q3);
            if ($r3->num_rows > 0) {
                if ($row3 = $r3->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row3['name'];
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row3['email'];
                    $_SESSION['user_fb_id'] = $row3['fb_id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_pundit_name'] = $row3['pundit_name'];
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row3['id'];
                    header('Location: ' . $site_url . 'whats_next.php');
                }
            }
        }*/
    }
}
else {
    echo 'error, you got the wrong email';
}

?>
```

Comment: check `session_id()` in both cases. if the id changes, then you've got something wrong with the cookie settings and are getting a different session in the 'bad' script.

Comment: Please add the url you're redirecting to, it could help, if you can show the actual url/domain, make it to localhost

Comment: where is `$site_url` being defined? probably why

Comment: or is that ^ irrelevant?

Comment: Yeah, `$site_url` was relevant after all. You should have shown that in your question as to how it was defined and what the URL was, it would have left the guesswork out of things. You got a lucky break from the answer given, otherwise your question would have probably been left unanswered for a long time.

Comment: the `$site_url` is the same in both cases ... it's loaded from settings.php ... the difference was that in the email confirmation link (which if clicked runs the "bad" script), I put in a www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had one similar issue once but it was for ASPx, still check if the url starts with or without "www" in both redirects, having them diff caused a new session id being created when I had the issue.Take a look it could be a similar case.

If someone wants to read about "www" and not "www" 
["URL with WWW and URL without WWW" -Is there any difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634218/url-with-www-and-url-without-www-is-there-any-difference-between-them)

Comment: Thanks this was the solution.